# .NET connection to SQL DB encrypted in webconfig

Tags: asp.net, database, security

We are developing an application with .NET and we are connecting to an SQL 2008 db on a windows server. Up until now we have been a small team which meant that the following code was acceptable:

```
<add key="ConnectionString" value="Server=00.000.000.00;uid=myUsername;pwd=myPassword;Database=myDatabase" />
```

This is then called when I want to connect to the database.

Our team is expanding and the new developers should not have access to the database credentials. They will have access to the application code and they have to connect to the database which is on a non-local server whilst running in debug mode locally.

What is the best (and fastest) solution to allow them to connect to the database without having credentials which will allow them to open the database and view the tables?

Comment: Why? The new developers would still have database access using the .NET Framework and could still issue any sql statements that their login allows them to.

Comment: @SimonSvensson Giving them access to the data in the database isn't a problem, we want to stop them having access to the stored procedures we have created

Comment: then don't give that sql-user access to the stored procedure. Nothing stops them from "SELECT * FROM sys.procedures;" and "EXEC dbo.MySecretProcedure;" once they get a database connection.

Comment: @SimonSvensson I don't care if they have a list of stored procedures, they need to call stored procedures from the application and print the data on the page, I just don't want them to view the code in the stored. You can't tell me that every developer who works on bank software has access to all of the database and can run whatever queries they like, that's impossible at a security level

Comment: `EXEC sp_helptext 'dbo.MyStoredProcedure';` will show the content of a stored procedure using another stored procedure. I know that some tools can decrypt encrypted stored procedures, dunno how they do that. I would say that banking has test-systems with test-data and sql-credentials which only allows them access to execute stored procedures. Thus they can not execute the contained sql-statements (select, update, ...) since they lack the permissions to do so.

Comment: @SimonSvensson So maybe you have offered a solution. Is it possible to create a sql user which has 1 possible access to the db: To call stored procedures. They can't open, view, launch custom queries? Is that possible?

Comment: no, it isn't. You will always have to give them a database connection to execute stored procedures, and that connection can always be used to execute any sql statement. (However, which objects their sql-statements can touch can be limited with permissions.) You can, however, create user that has access to execute stored procedures, without access to any tables. You could deny them the permissions to "ALTER, CONTROL, TAKE OWNERSHIP, or VIEW DEFINITION" which are the permissions for sp_helptext, according to the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest and easiest solution would be to encrypt the ConnectionString in your `config` file. It's pretty simply to do as well.

Open CMD change the directory to the .NET Framework version (your prefered version) directory by typing the following command:

```
cd \WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\Framework\yourversion     
At the command prompt, run aspnet_regiis.exe with the following options:
The -pe option and the string "connectionStrings" to encrypt the connectionStrings element of the Web.config file for your application.
The -app option and the name of your application.
```

For example, the following command encrypts the  section of the Web.config file for an application named MyApplication.

```
aspnet_regiis -pe "connectionStrings" -app "/MyApplication"
```

The encrypted `connectionString` will look something like

```
<connectionStrings configProtectionProvider="RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider">
  <EncryptedData Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
     <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#tripledes-cbc" />
     <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <EncryptedKey xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
           <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5" />
           <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
              <KeyName>RSA Key
              </KeyName>
           </KeyInfo>
           <CipherData>
              <CipherValue>WcFEbDX8VyLfAsVK8g6hZVAG1674ZFc1kWH0BoazgOwdBfinhcAmQmnIn0oHtZ5tO2EXGl+dyh10giEmO9NemH4YZk+iMIln+ItcEay9CGWMXSen9UQLpcQHQqMJErZiPK4qPZaRWwqckLqriCl9X8x9OE7jKIsO2Ibapwj+1Jo=
              </CipherValue>
           </CipherData>
        </EncryptedKey>
     </KeyInfo>
     <CipherData>
        <CipherValue>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
        </CipherValue>
     </CipherData>
  </EncryptedData>
</connectionStrings>
```

You can **[this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dtkwfdky%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)** article for more information

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the only question I have is that it says "Microsoft Internet Information Services (IIS) installed and configured on the computer that will host the site.". If the developers are running VS2012 and are running the application on localhost, does your answer apply? Do I have to install IIS on their computers?

Comment: This seems to require shared machinekeys, which means that the new developers could decrypt the connections.

Comment: The developer will require read access to the encryption key.